# Curser deletes the character - Spyder program

Tags: python, while-loop, spyder, typing

Would like to know if there is a way in Spyder program that you can replace the black fat cursor with the regular line  which is always overwriting the existing text so when I make a small typo I am forced to delete the whole line up until that point.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your are in insert mode? Try to press the `insert` key on your keyboard.